# pyside2uic.Compiler import error

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pyside2

Using pyside2uic I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyside2-uic", line 7, in <module>
    from PySide2.scripts.uic import main
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PySide2/scripts/uic.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pyside2uic.driver import Driver
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyside2uic/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pyside2uic.Compiler import indenter, compiler
ImportError: No module named Compiler
```

OS: Centos 7.4.1708

Comment: Centos 7.4  :  »» No module named **Compiler** «« `$ find /usr/lib64/ -iname "compiler.py"` → /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/compiler.py .... `$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/compiler.py` → PyQt4-4.10.1-13.el7.x86_64 . Please note that you have an upper case "**Compiler** error". An error in your program ? **C** to be c ? Or may be reinstall the package: `# yum reinstall PyQt4-4.10.1-13.el7.x86_64`

Comment: Actually it's PyQt5 and PySide2. I have discovered that Anaconda has its own pyside2 bindings and it works fine.